# android 4 emulator cannot connect with localhost

Tags: android, api, localhost, emulation, loopj

I want to connect with my web API, its URL is `http://localhost:55154/`, with android emulator.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.get("http://10.0.2.2:55154/api/values", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {    
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
```

I'm getting no response, however, when I connect to `google.pl` I'm getting a proper response.
I have tried multiple variants with the localhost address, but none is working.

Im using this liblary for my async connection:
[`http://loopj.com/android-async-http/`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

**UPDATE:**

When I'm running my program I'm getting the following error from the LogCat

```
07-17 08:58:26.495: E/Trace(879): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

However I am able to conect with `http://localhost:55154/api/values` via my browser.

Answer (score 0):

use the IP address `10.0.2.2` not `10.0.0.2`

reference http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: I had 10.0.2.2 before, i posted wrong code because i was changing it some many times. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this `http://10.0.2.2:55154/` to connect with your port address